# Categorising Database Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering what peoples thoughts are on this.....

I have a list of names (e.g. company names), and want to display them as a list on a webpage. I'd like for users to be able to find a group of names by alphabetical letter. So if they click on 'M' then it will show company names that begin with the letter M. This sounds easy enough right?

However, here's the catch: not all company names that should be in the 'M' category will start with the letter M e.g. University of Michigan. So using

```
SELECT * WHERE Name LIKE 'M%'
```

in a SQL query will not work here.

What would be the best way to go about categorising data in this way?

The only way I can think of is to add a column in the company names table and manually assign an alphabet letter to each company name so that it can be used in a SELECT statement later. This sounds so tedious and rudimentary I'm hoping there's a better way to solve the task? In case anyone is wondering I am using ColdFusion as my back-end software to display data on a webpage.

Thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: The viability of a rule (e.g. "the word after 'of' when it appears in the name is the primary sort-term) will depend on the uniformity of the names.  It might work with university names, but with company-names there could be significantly more variation, leading to guesswork.  Data management is not devoid of tedium, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to put any name in any "letter category" arbitrarily, then adding a column is your only option. If you can define a specific set of rules that determine which letter category the name must be sorted by, then you can write a sorting function in CF (or JS).

Answer (score 2):

If each company name is going to have exactly one category, and you have to guess what the category is, then having a separate column is the right approach.

If you just want a "good enough" guess, where a company name can appear in more than one list, then you might put it in the category of the first letter of any word in the name:

```
select *
from t
where ' '+name like ' M%'
```

You could then get fancy by removing some words, but this requires multiple replaces:

```
where ' '+replace(replace(replace(name, ' of', ''), 'University', ''), ' the', '') like ' M%'
```

However, that is a bit ad hoc for long term use.  And it could mess up on something like "The Office Group".

Answer (score 2):

Considering that these are company names, you could rely on their capital letter being either at the beginning of their name or prepended with a white space in the middle of the description:

```
SELECT * WHERE Name LIKE 'M%' OR Name LIKE '% M%';
```

In this way "University of Michigan" will be listed under letter U and M (which I presume it is a nice thing to have), and so will be "McDonald" or "University of McDonald", but not under "D" as this letter is not prepended by a space.